# "cannot concatenate 'str' and 'float' objects" even though i used str()

Tags: python, python-2.x

```
print 'You got' + str(score) + 'out of' + str(max_score)
print 'That\'s' + str(percentage) + '%'
```

Even though I changed the type to string, it still gives me this

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "maniasimplescoring.py", line 37, in <module>
print 'You got' + score + 'out of' + max_score
TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'float' objects
```

What am I doing wrong?

EDIT: apparently my changes weren't saving. I changed it in a different editor and it worked

Comment: My only guess is that what you're doing wrong is not showing us the exact code that threw that error message.  Also, you're not showing us the entire error message - that could be helpful too.

Comment: use `.format` for better output layout

Comment: @Brionius that is the code that does it, the rest of the file works fine on it's own

Comment: According to the entire error message, that is **not** the code that threw the error message.  You were running this code:  `print 'You got' + score + 'out of' + max_score` when you got that error.

Comment: yeah thanks, looks like it wasn't saving for some reason.

Answer (score 2):

Use format, for better readability:

```
print 'You got {0} out of {1}'.format(score, max_score)
print "That's {0}%".format(percentage)
```

Comment: I beat you to it by less than a minute :P

Answer (score 1):

This should fix it:

```
print 'You got {} out of {}'.format(score, max_score)
print 'That\'s {}%'.format(percentage)
```